# How to upload .jar file in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, jar, upload

I want to upload jar in my Wordpress website. But it seems that Wordpress does not allow to upload this type of file. I am using Wordpress 3.8.2. Any help and suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have ftp access you can upload it that way.

Comment: I have edited functions.php and now it is working fine..I can upload it using the flash uploader Thanks any way.

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared what you did

Comment: I can't understand why this is a problem in the first place. Why doesn't Wordpress allow such files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to get your hands dirty and want to keep easy access to these settings, install a plugin that enables you to do this. For instance this plugin works well for me: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-add-mime-types/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rather than editing core files (which is **always** a bad idea), you should consider adding a filter by hooking into the [`mime_types`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/2583c1e4ec68275926c27c57913ace6ee9e3ac36/wp-includes/functions.php#L2239) filter:

```
/**
 * Add JAR file type to list of allowed extensions 
 * 
 * @param array $types Default allowed mime types
 */
function so23113552_custom_mime_types( $types ) {

    $types['jar'] = 'application/java-jar';

    return $types;
}
add_filter( 'mime_types', 'so23113552_custom_mime_types' );
```